# MSChart - RangeBar Series Label alignment

Tags: alignment, label, mschart, microsoft-chart-controls

I have a RangeBar chart that looks like the image below. I want to align the Series Labels so that they appear at the **top** of the bar instead of centered.

Things I've discovered:

`SmartLabelStyle` doesn't work with Bar chart types

`LabelStyle` custom property doesn't seem to do anything either

Does anyone have any other ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks

[image: Range Bar Chart Labels]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just used `TextAnnotation` instead of `Series.Label` and played some games positioning them suing the `AnchorX` and `AnchorY` properties.